# Setup automated calling during an ETL failure

Tags: automation, telephone

Just started working on a large data warehouse project that runs some large ETLs every night.  In the event of an error I receive an email, but I was hoping to somehow create something that will automatically call me, so I don't have to wake up and check my email at 4 every morning to make sure the ETLs finished properly.  I know I can setup an SMS pretty easily, but I don't think that will be enough to wake me up :)

Anyone have any experience trying to do this before?

Comment: Is this on Windows? Linux? Do you have a modem available and a physical phone line?

Comment: It's on windows, and I would probably be able to setup a phone line and modem,

Answer (score 1):

SMS seems a good mechanism for this. Can't you just set up a louder notification signal on your cellphone? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if you are not responsible for network infrastructure and it is pretty reliable - you can use command-line based sip client to initiate a call and possibly some voice synthetizer to read messages. [nagios](http://nagios.org/) will provide you a nice framework to orchestrate the checks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://www.pagerduty.com/

- is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Basically that is what I'm looking for, but it has a lot of extra fluff I don't need.  All I need is just to set it up so I will get a phone call when there is a failure.  I was hoping to see if there was an easy way to implement it myself.  But if not, this looks like a good option.

Comment: Yes - just to say this service is currently free (from looking at the site), so no harm in trying it out...